# when call like stringResource(2131623990) it crash if call stringResource(R.string.error) not why

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

let suppose the id of "R.string.error" is 2131623990. when call

```
stringResource(2131623990)
```

it crash if call

```
stringResource(R.string.error)
```

not why

when call

```
stringResource(2131623990)
```

it crash if call

```
stringResource(R.string.error)
```

not why

Comment: Are you certain that `2131623990` is consistent across builds? It may be regenerated every time you rebuild your app.

Comment: try calling the numbers inside parenthesis, like
stringResource(id = (2131623990))

Comment: i tried these all thing i used debugged to check difference but the code was same when i call it like  'stringResource(R.string.something) ' it run if i call its id it crash throw  'PID: 3703
                                                                                                    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff
 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:493)at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:589)' @PPartisan

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that R class is imported from correct package.
Just scroll up, take a look into imports, you should have something like  `import com.somepackage.R`.

Make sure that import is from module that you have access to.

Could you please show logs with crash ? What exception is thrown ?

Comment: `  PID: 3703
                                                                                                    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:493) at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:589)`

Comment: where this method "stringResource()" came from ? Could you show it implementation ?

Comment: fun String.isValidUsername(): Int? {
    val trimmedUsername = trim()
    return when {
        trimmedUsername.length < 6 -> R.string.enter_valid_username_length
        trimmedUsername.matches(Regex("^[0-9]+$")) -> R.string.enter_valid_username_number
        trimmedUsername.matches(Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")) ->null
        else -> R.string.username_should_only_be_alpha_numeric
    }
}

Comment: if (userName.isValidUsername() != null) {
                                errorUsernameState = ErrorState(
                                    isError = true, (userName.isValidUsername()!!)
                                )
                                return@Button
                            }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use getString to get string resource

```
getString(R.string.stringname)
```

and dont put your full error message or full code in comment because will make other confuse